# Sorting string occurrences from text file

Tags: java, arraylist, hashset

I have stored strings from a file into an ArrayList, and used a HashSet to count the number of occurrences of each string.

I am looking to list the top 5 words and their number of occurrences. I should be able to accomplish this w/o implementing a hashtable, treemap, etc. How can I go about achieving this?

Here is my ArrayList:

```
List<String> word_list = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (INPUT_TEXT1.hasNext()) {
            String input_word = INPUT_TEXT1.next();
            word_list.add(input_word);

        }

        INPUT_TEXT1.close();

        int word_list_length = word_list.size();



        System.out.println("There are " + word_list_length + " words in the .txt file");
        System.out.println("\n\n");

        System.out.println("word_list's elements are: ");



        for (int i = 0; i<word_list.size(); i++) {
                System.out.print(word_list.get(i) + "  ");

            }

        System.out.println("\n\n");
```

Here is my HashSet:

```
Set<String> unique_word = new HashSet<String>(word_list);

    int number_of_unique = unique_word.size();

    System.out.println("unique worlds are: ");

    for (String e : unique_word) {
        System.out.print(e + " ");

    }

    System.out.println("\n\n");


    String [] word = new String[number_of_unique];
    int [] freq = new int[number_of_unique];

    int count = 0;

    System.out.println("Frequency counts : ");

    for (String e : unique_word) {
        word[count] = e;
        freq[count] = Collections.frequency(word_list, e);



        System.out.println(word[count] + " : "+ freq[count] + " time(s)");
        count++;

    }
```

Could it be that I am overthinking a step? Thanks in advance

Comment: Create an inner class, say Z, having two fields - word, count which implements `Comparable<Z>` and overrides the `hashcode()` and `equals()` method. Create set of instances of this class - if set contains the object obtain it and increment count. Sort it using `Collections.sort()`. And there you go.

Comment: That said, Hashmap is probably the better way to do it

Comment: There's a easy implementation in Apache Commons, using `HashBag`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `HashMap` (holds with unique word as `key` and frequency as `value`) and then sorting the `values` in the reverse order as explained in the below steps:

(1) Load the `word_list` with the words

(2) Find the unique words from `word_list`

(3) Store the unique words into `HashMap` with unique word as `key` and frequency as `value`

(4) Sort the `HashMap` with value (frequency)

**You can refer the below code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> word_list = new ArrayList<>();
        //Load your words to the word_list here

        //Find the unique words now from list
        String[] uniqueWords = word_list.stream().distinct().
                                       toArray(size -> new String[size]);
        Map<String, Integer> wordsMap = new HashMap<>();
        int frequency = 0;

        //Load the words to Map with each uniqueword as Key and frequency as Value
        for (String uniqueWord : uniqueWords) {
            frequency = Collections.frequency(word_list, uniqueWord);
            System.out.println(uniqueWord+" occured "+frequency+" times");
            wordsMap.put(uniqueWord, frequency);
        }

       //Now, Sort the words with the reverse order of frequency(value of HashMap)
       Stream<Entry<String, Integer>> topWords = wordsMap.entrySet().stream().
         sorted(Map.Entry.<String,Integer>comparingByValue().reversed()).limit(5);

        //Now print the Top 5 words to console
        System.out.println("Top 5 Words:::");
        topWords.forEach(System.out::println);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using java 8 and putting all code in one block.

```
 Stream<Map.Entry<String,Long>> topWords =
            words.stream()
                    .map(String::toLowerCase)
                    .collect(groupingBy(identity(), counting()))
                    .entrySet().stream()
                    .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long> comparingByValue(reverseOrder())
                            .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))
                    .limit(5);
```

Iterate over stream

```
topWords.forEach(m -> {
            System.out.print(m.getKey() + " : "+ m.getValue() + "time(s)");
        });
```